# how to make this function syncornus (nodejs and mongodb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i cant seem to make it work in order and it will return `undefined` every time
so how can i make it so the `console.log` shows it after the function is done?

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
let datad;
function search(dbol, collection, query, callback) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db(dbol);
    dbo
      .collection(collection)
      .find(query)
      .toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // console.log(result);
        datad = JSON.stringify(result);
        console.log(datad);
        db.close();
        return result;
      });
  });

  return datad;
}

var query = { user: "admin" };
console.log(search("storageinterface", "user", query));
console.log(datad);
```

the console.log inside the function gives the correct value but i cant get it out of the function in time

Comment: You can't make an asynchronous call synchronous. If you're open to using promises, promisifying the function would be easiest. See https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/promises/#promises-and-callbacks

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve. Either use promise or await/async. Or if you want some function to be executed only after search is done, maybe you can try using the callback param in the search function.

Comment: Mostly a duplicate of [How to return an asynchronous response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).  And, there is now way (in nodejs) to convert an asynchronous operation to a synchronous one.  You cannot directly return an asynchronously retrieved value.  Instead (as indicated in my link above), you must use a callback, a promise or an event to communicate back the asynchronous value.